# How to remove Chrome bookmark folder icon?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'd like to have a certain Chome bookmark folder without the folder icon. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is old and likely abandoned.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace the generic folder icon with some other icon, or; you want to remove it completely? If the latter, then the answer is easy. However, I don't want to post and guess at the correct answer. I think that your question needs an [edit] to clarify what you mean exactly.